# show hidden div with jquery by url

Tags: jquery, url, web

i am us jquery to show/hide divs by button click which works well but i would like to be able to show the div using a url: eg: somesite.com/page.php#ShowThisDiv

This is the jquery i am using:

```
$(function () {
    $('#Options ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newcontent = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#Options ul li a').removeClass('sel');
        $(this).addClass('sel');

        $('#Info section').each(function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('hidden')) {
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
            }
        });

        $(newcontent).removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain javascript to get the ID out the url:

```
var url = 'http://somesite.com/page.php#ShowThisDiv';
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#'));
alert(id); //outputs #ShowThisDiv
```

**UPDATE:**

```
function loadDiv() {
    var url = window.location; //Example: http://somesite.com/page.php#ShowThisDiv
    var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#'));
    $(id).show(); //Displays the div #ShowThisDiv
}

loadDiv();
```

**UPDATE 2**

*HTML*

```
<div class="divs" id="div1">...</div>
<div class="divs" id="div2">...</div>
<div class="divs" id="div3">...</div>
<div class="divs" id="div4">...</div>
```

*JS*

```
function loadDiv() {
   //Hide divs
   $('.divs').hide();

   //Get div to show
   var url = window.location; //Example: http://somesite.com/page.php#div1
   var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#'));

   //Show div
   $(id).show(); //Displays the div #div1
}

loadDiv();
```

Comment: What mean is i want to link to and show to the div from another page so if i am on the home page and i cic page2.php#DivName it will go to page 2 and show the hidden div

Comment: See update, place it in a seperated js file. Load the div whenever you want by calling the `loadDiv()` function. Then get the url using `window.location` and take the div to show.

Comment: thanks that does work bt can i ask if the page has a selected div already show how would i hide it so only one div is showing

Comment: Therefore I need to see the html of the divs, what you can do is assign a equal class to all divs and hide all these divs using the class selector and then show the correct div using the Id from the url